# too many redirects while creating a new session

Tags: ruby-on-rails

a user of my website must first login to see every page of it. My current solution results in a "too many redirects" error message in the browser, I suspect something goes wrong so it endlessly goes back and forth, but where?

In the application controller I have this:

```
before_filter :authenticate_user

def authenticate_user
  unless session[:user_id]
    flash[:alert] = I18n.t :session_unauthenticated
    redirect_to login_path
  end
end
```

The "login_path" goes to "sessions/new", which looks like this:

```
    def new
      user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
      if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
        session[:user_id] = user.id
        redirect_to root_url, :notice => I18n.t(:session_logged_in)
      else
        flash.now.alert = I18n.t(:session_invalid)
        render "new"
      end  
    end
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: what should authenticate_user return if the session[user_id] does exist?  I would try changing the unless to a regular if, e.g. if session[:user_id] return true else flash & redirect

Comment: The filter does not have to return at all. The idea is to just redirect if the user is not authenticated.

Comment: Indeed, if there is a session ID then the user is logged in and authorized to see the page he requested, so no action is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `before_filter` is active for each and every action (since it's in the `ApplicationController`) and therefore also for your `sessions#new` action. Meaning you cannot even enter the login action. I suggest you put the `before_filter` in every needed controller and specify the actions with `before_filter :authenticate_user, :except => [:new, :create, :destroy]` or whatever you need.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem. However to make the solution more DRY I will use a "skip_filter" in the sessions controller instead of adding a before_filter in every other controller.